# Create custom Java based extension in Gatling (version 3.8.4)

Tags: gatling

I am trying to create my own extension (in Java language) for Gatling (version 3.8.4).
Can you please point me the steps to be followed ?

I could see some articles on creating custom extension in Scala but not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible atm. Core Gatling is written in Scala, not Java. The Java layer is only a wrapper on top of the Scala one.